# How to align divs in 960 grid system

Tags: html, css

I've recently been learning CSS and getting into the 960 grid system. I'm now stuck and I want to know how I should properly align two or more divs to my website here.

So, what I want to do it is to align the grid 3 and grid 4 divs horizontally.

```
<div class="container_12">
    <div class="grid_12" id="img"></div>
    <div class="clear"></div>

    <div class="grid_12" id="navbar">
        <ul>
            <li>Home</li>
            <li>Portfolio</li>
            <li>About</li>
            <li>Contact</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>

    <div class="grid_12 spacer"></div>
    <div class="clear"></div>

    <div class="grid_12" id="info_wrapper">
        <div class="grid_3">Lorem Ipsum</div>
        <div class="grid_3">Lorem Ipsum</div>
        <div class="grid_3">Lorem Ipsum</div>
        <div class="grid_3">Lorem Ipsum</div>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>

    <div class="grid_12 spacer"></div>
    <div class="clear"></div>

    <div class="grid_4">Lorem Ipsum</div>
    <div class="grid_4">Lorem Ipsum</div>
    <div class="grid_4">Lorem Ipsum</div>
    <div class="clear"></div>

    <div class="grid_12 spacer"></div>
    <div class="clear"></div>

    <div class="grid_12" id="footer">
        <div class="grid_4 alpha">Lorem Ipsum</div>
        <div class="grid_4">Lorem Ipsum</div>
        <div class="grid_4 omega">Lorem Ipsum</div>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: A demo here would be useful.

Answer (score 0):

Always use flex-box to format and align your content with css. I cannot stress the power and ease of flex-box enough. Here is a working solution to your problem using flex-box:
http://codepen.io/pen/?editors=110

One other thing to note:
Only add an html element such as a div when it is absolutely necessary. Cluttering a page with tons of divs is not considered semantic so keep that in mind moving forward.

here is another great flex-box recourse for future projects:
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

happy coding,
Alex

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.grid_3{
  height:100px;
  width: 50%;
  background-color:yellow;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.grid_4{
  height:100px;
  width: 50%;
  background-color:red;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.flexer {
  display: flex;
}

#footer {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container_12">
    <div class="grid_12" id="img"></div>
    <div class="clear"></div>

    <div class="grid_12" id="navbar">
        <ul>
            <li>Home</li>
            <li>Portfolio</li>
            <li>About</li>
            <li>Contact</li>
        </ul>
    </div>

  <div class='flexer'>
        <div class="grid_3">Lorem Ipsum</div>
        <div class="grid_3">Lorem Ipsum</div>
        <div class="grid_3">Lorem Ipsum</div>
        <div class="grid_3">Lorem Ipsum</div>
   
        <div class="grid_4">Lorem Ipsum</div>
        <div class="grid_4">Lorem Ipsum</div>
        <div class="grid_4">Lorem Ipsum</div>
  </div>

    <div id="footer">
        <div class="alpha">Lorem Ipsum</div>
        <div class="">Lorem Ipsum</div>
        <div class="omega">Lorem Ipsum</div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: here is a working codepen link to your project, I believe. http://codepen.io/alexG53090/pen/wMaJKb?editors=110